# VBA How do i split an integer into separate parts

Tags: vba, excel, split, integer

I'm working in VBA within Excel.
I need to split the integer into two parts, specifically the first two digits and the last two digits.
The numbers have a maximum of four digits and at least one. (I've already sorted out the blank values) eg.

7 should become 0 and 7,

23 should become 0 and 23,

642 should become 6 and 42,

1621 should become 16 and 21.

This is the code I have so far

```
Function Bloog(value1 As Integer)

Dim value1Hours, value1Mins As Integer

Select Case Len(value1) 'gives a number depending on the length of the value1
    Case 1, 2 ' e.g., 2 = 0, 2 or 16 = 0, 16
        value1Hours = 0
        value1Mins = value1
    Case 3 ' e.g., 735 = 7, 35
        value1Hours = Left(value1, 1) ' 7
        value1Mins = Right(value1, 2) ' 35
    Case 4 ' e.g., 1234 = 12, 34
        value1Hours = Left(value1, 2) ' 12
        value1Mins = Right(value1, 2) ' 34
End Select
```

However when go to get the values i find that they have not been split up into the separate parts as the Left() and Right() function would have me believe.
Len() doesn't appear to be working either, when it was given the value 723 it returned a length of 2.

Any tips would be appreciated.

=======================================

After a suggestion I've cast the values as strings then done the case statement and converted them back afterwards. (because I need them for some calculations)

```
Private Function Bloog(value1 As Integer) As Integer

Dim strValue1 As String
Dim strValue1Hours, strValue1Mins As String
Dim value1Hours, value1Mins As Integer

'converts the values into strings for the Left() and Right() functions
strValue1 = CStr(value1)

Select Case Len(value1) 'gives a number depending on the length of the value1
    Case 1, 2 ' e.g., 2 = 0, 2 or 16 = 0, 16
        strValue1Hours = 0
        strValue1Mins = value1
    Case 3 ' e.g., 735 = 7, 35
        strValue1Hours = Left(value1, 1) ' 7
        strValue1Mins = Right(value1, 2) ' 35
    Case 4 ' e.g., 1234 = 12, 34
        strValue1Hours = Left(value1, 2) ' 12
        strValue1Mins = Right(value1, 2) ' 34
End Select

value1Hours = CInt(strValue1Hours)
value1Mins = CInt(strValue1Mins)
```

Len() still believes that the length of the string is 2 and so case 2 statement was triggered, despite this the the strValue1Mins and the value1Mins still equals 832.

=======================

Len() was testing for Value1 not strValue1, everything works fine after that.

Comment: @MitchWheat, I'm able to use LEFT() and RIGHT() on numbers.

Comment: @Jar, edit the code and set `value1 = 735`. When I run your code it works. You sure value1 is sent correctly?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat - So if i was to cast them then this should fix it?

Comment: @t.thielemans, yeah I've checked it in debug mode, it definitely gets through.

Comment: @t.thielemans - that's what i'm really not understanding

Comment: @Jar, when you use a pre-defined value for `value1`, you'll see that your code works. I would look for the problem before you enter that function ;)

Comment: @t.thielemans -  i just realised what the Len issue is, i'm still testing for value1 NOT strValue1, that's why the result is 2! EVERYTHING NOW WORKS. YIPEEEEEEE!

Comment: Ok, but for examples of less clumsy programming, see the answers below!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

value1 is an integer, why not use arithmetic operations ?

```
Dim value1Hours as Integer,value1Mins as Integer
value1Mins = value1 Mod 100
value1Hours = Int(value1 / 100)
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps.  This is the most simple way that I could think of.

```
ValueAsString = Right("0000" & value1,4)
strValue1Hours = Left(ValueAsString, 2)
strValue1Mins = Right(ValueAsString, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth:

```
    value1Hours = CInt(Left(Format(x, "0000"), 2))
    value1Mins = CInt(Right(Format(x, "0000"), 2))
```